# QT: list of item from multiple spinboxes

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

Is it possible to get a list of values from each spinbox and put them into a list?

```
for (int i = 0; i < norm_size+1; i++){
    getSpinleftValue(i);
}
```

I use a for loop to set up all my connections

```
.
void GuiTest::getSpinleftValue(int index){
    QSpinBox* spinleft[norm_size+1] = {ui->norm_spinBox_9,
                                       ui->norm_spinBox_10,
                                       ui->norm_spinBox_11,
                                       ui->norm_spinBox_12,
                                       ui->norm_spinBox_13,
                                       ui->norm_spinBox_14,
                                       ui->norm_spinBox_15,
                                       ui->norm_spinBox_16};
    QObject::connect(spinleft[index], SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(spinboxWrite(int, index)));
}
.
```

then once the connections are made by the for loop, I wanted to write their outputs into a list to be used later.

```
.
void GuiTest::spinboxWrite(int arg1, int index){
    int norm_list[16];
    qDebug() << arg1;
    qDebug() << index;
}
```

in this case I'm using some debug functions so I can see if they're working. Right now it doesn't look like it's working, because I'm not writing the "connect" part right.

```
No such slot GuiTest::spinboxWrite(int, index) in
```

I know the other solution is to create a bunch of these

```
void GuiTest::on_norm_spinBox_9_valueChanged(int arg1)
{
    //code here
}
```

But I'd rather not pollute my entire file with **16** of these if I can help it!

Comment: You can use the same function for multiple spinboxes. That should get you down to 2 functions.

Comment: You didn't show how you connect the signals to the slots, but it should be something like `connect(spinbox1, valueChanged, guitest, on_norm_spinBox_valueChanged);`.

Comment: I use the gui designer that comes with QtCreator. It does that for me.

Comment: In the gui designer you should be able to open the .ui file, click on the "Edit Signals/Slots" and drag an arrow from a spinbox to the window, then select `valueChanged(int)` on the left and some function on the right. You can choose the same function on the right for multiple spinboxes.

Comment: I just tried what you suggested. But i'm not sure what _"to the window"_ is referring to.

Comment: To the window where the spinbox is located in. You will then need to add slots for that window. How did you get the spinboxes connected to your functions?

Comment: Click on **Edit Widgets** (or press F3) then right click on a **spin box**, then click on **go to slot**  a window titled _"Go to Slot"_ will appear, I then clicked on **valueChanged(int)**. Then the gui created the function for me.

Comment: This will create a slot for you, which is good. You can then in the "Edit Signals/Slots" mode drag an arrow from another spinbox to the window behind it, which opens a "Configure Connection" window where on the right side click "Edit...", press the green + for Slots, replace `Slot()` with `on_spinBox_valueChanged(int)` and press Ok. You can now connect the `valueChanged(int)` signal on the left with the `on_spinBox_valueChanged(int)` slot on the right and do the same for any number of spinboxes.

Comment: more importantly will it create this output? **[0,0], [1,1], [2,2], [3,3], [4,4], [5,5], [6,6], [7,7]**

Comment: [link]http://i.imgur.com/8SrV8S6.png I think i did it right. Here's what I'm looking at

Comment: @nwp, i'm blocked from chat, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signal `valueChanged(int)` and your slot `spinboxWrite(int, index)` (note that index is not even a type in your case!) do not have matching signatures, so `connect` won't work. From the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#signals-and-slots-with-default-arguments):

> the signature passed to the SIGNAL() macro must not have fewer arguments than the signature passed to the SLOT() macro.

I think that the simplest way to solve your problems would be connecting the `valueChanged(int)` signal from all the spin boxes to the same slot and use [`sender`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) to get the spin box that was changed, Here is how you would do that, in the constructor:

```
GuiTest::GuiTest(QWidget* parent)/*do you initializations*/{

    //after setup ui, create your spin boxes. . .

    //get list of all children spin boxes
    //(you can replace that with a hard coded list if it is 
    //not applicable)
    QList<QSpinBox*> spinBoxes= findChildren<QSpinBox*>();
    //connect the signal from all spin boxes to the slot
    QSpinBox* spinBox;
    foreach(spinBox, spinBoxes)
        connect(spinBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(SpinBoxChanged(int)));
}
```

and here is how your `spinboxWrite` slot would look like:

```
void GuiTest::SpinBoxChanged(int value){
    QSpinBox* sp= qobject_cast<QSpinBox*>(sender());

    //now sp is a pointer to the QSpinBox that emitted the valueChanged signal
    //and value is its value after the change
    //do whatever you want to do with them here. . .

}
```

Comment: you seem to have edited your question before I posted my answer, if this answer is not applicable to your question I will delete it

Comment: Thank you, Mike. Let me try it out. I read through your comments, it might work.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I will mark you as the solution. This is really clever, and after running it in the debugger it seems to be what i think i need.

Comment: should I revert the changes on my question? So your answer is relevant?

Comment: @tisaconundrum , I think your question after editing is less accurate and understandable than before editing,  so I think that you should revert it

Comment: Thanks again Mike, this helped a lot

Comment: @tisaconundrum , apologizes for editing the answer. There is no need to use `QSignalMapper` here, this is a simpler answer. I wasn't alert enough, sorry.